# Minitest assert can't see date value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, simple-form, minitest

I'd asked a question about this date field a few days ago but was able to test against the ID though the text label of the field was not being found even though the source clearly shows it.

Now I'm testing the actual value of the date.   My test is simple:

```
assert page.has_content?("2015-02-26"), "Content - 2015-02-26 not available."
```

Here's the source of the page loaded in the browser:

```
  <div class="form-group date required visit_date_of_visit">
    <label class="date required control-label" for="visit_date_of_visit_1i">
    <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Date of visit</label>
    <input class="date required form-control" value="2015-02-26" type="date" name="visit[date_of_visit]" id="visit_date_of_visit" /></div>
```

As you see, the value is there.

Now, this is the source.   In the actual browser this is 02/26/2015 as I have it formatted that way and the actual code works.   Even though it shows this as the value, the code itself shows something else.   But the test does not find this OR that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't be more specific? and instead searching in all page content just search for fields:

```
page.has_field?('name_of_filed', :with => 'filed_value')
```

In your case

```
page.has_field?('visit[date_of_visit]', :type => 'date', :with => '2015-02-26')
```

For more options visit [Capybara documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_field%3F-instance_method)

Comment: I've actually done that and it CAN find "visit_date_of_visit" but not the name "Date of visit" which you see is visible and available.   Was just wondering why it can't actually find the content clearly available for it to find but CAN find the id visit_date_of_visit.

Comment: "page.had_field?" 'll only look for HTML form elements. "Date of visit" is not any filed name, its label. For labels you should use "page.has_content"

Comment: That is interesting.   I have has_field in other places with the label name and it works perfectly.   It's only this one that it doesn't.   Let me find that code and I'll show you :).